# Cut line, trim it and then paste it on another line

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I sometimes have to cut a line (`d`) and paste in in the middle of another line. I'd like to remove the whitespaces that vim has copied (i.e. trim/strip the content). How can I do that in vim?

A common use case is that.

```
value := getValue()
if value == "test" {
    // Do something with value
```

In go, it is idiomatic to use `if value := getValue(); value == "test"` if value is only used within the if. However, sometimes I write the variable declaration outside of the if because I either used the variable after the if (and later moved that code inside the if), or because I simply forgot it. So, I'd like to cut the line `value := getValue()` and paste it after `if`. If I press `p` or `P`, it is inserted after (or before) the current line. Can I somehow insert that line onto the current line and remove the starting/trailing whitespaces (tabs, new lines, and )? I often have to do that in Latex documents, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to the line with `getValue()` and do something like <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to cut the contents, then go to the space after `if` and press <kbd>p</kbd> to paste it.  This is not perfect because it leaves an empty line (more precisely a line with spaces) where `getValue()` has been, and you need to add a space after pasting.  But it's still a lot better than pasting the entire line.

If you feel like learning something useful, run `:h operator` and read the entire chapter there.  Pay particular attention to "text objects", those are one of the most powerful intermediate level concepts in Vim.  When you feel comfortable with the built-in text objects you can install the [textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) plugin, and add support for [many other objects](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/wiki).  In particular the [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) plugin adds support for Go functions as objects (among many other things), and [textobj-latex](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex) adds support for equation objects in LaTeX.

Comment: Actually instead of `^ d $` you can do `_ D` (underscore capital d) to cut to end (without newline) from the beginning of text. (this will ignore indenting whitespace at start of line). Might be a bit easier to type.