# Cut a regex matching line and paste it at another line

Tags: cut-copy-paste, filetype-json

I am trying to edit a json file, and I need to take out the lines starting and ending with `{%` and `%}` respectively and move them to the beginning of the file. I need to do it at different places in a single file and repeat it for a lot of files, hence I am looking for a single command to this for one place and then I can repeat it again and again.

Ex.
Current file:

```
{% data 1 %}

{

  "data1": [

     detail1a: data detail 1a

     detail1b: data detail 1b

  ]

}

{% data 2a %}

{% data 2b %}

{

  "data2": [

     detail2a: data detail 2a

     detail2b: data detail 2b

  ]

}

{% data 3a %}

{

  "data3": [

     detail3a: data detail 3a

  ]

}

In this file, i want to remove all the data xa/xb lines and paste them at the beginning of the file like:

{% data 1 %}

{% data 2a %}

{% data 2b %}

{% data 3a %}
<rest of the lines>% data 3a %}
```

Then I can use `:%s/^\(\s\+\)]\n}\n{$/\1],/g` to remove the }{ to join it  as a single execution.

I can do `/^{%.*%}$` to get the line but how do I cut it and move it to line 0 (pushing down whatever is at line 0 already).

Any help appreciated.

PS: This is my first post in stackechange and I tried looking for all the existing posts to my best. The closet I found is this ([Cut line, trim it and then paste it on another line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/cut-line-trim-it-and-then-paste-it-on-another-line)) but it doesn't solve my purpose. Please excuse if I missed some norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct solution is a `:global` command:

```
:g/^{%.*%}$/m0
```

The slight problem is that this leaves the lines in reverse order. A simple solution is just to run it again! (By pressing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.)

If that seems inelegant to you, it's also possible to do it in a single pass. Here's one way:

```
:2mark a
:2,$g/^{%.*%}$/normal! dd'aP
```

Noting that the first line is already in the correct place, we first set a mark `a` on the second line. We then run a `:normal` command on each of the remaining matching lines to move each of them above the line we just marked.

For more details, see:

- `:help :global`
- `:help :move`
- `:help :normal`
- `:help cmdline-ranges`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your quick help.